# check validation conditionally in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I've a user manager in my project. When i'm adding user all validations must be called but according to my requirement when i'm email & password from user to login then i want that ***isunique*** validation for email address not be called.

UserController.php

```
public function login() {
        $this->layout = 'login';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            /** these conditions are used to call validations forcefully **/
            if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
                $this->User->set($this->request->data);
                if($this->User->validates()) {
                }
            } else {
                $errors = $this->User->invalidFields();
            }
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } else {
                //$errors = "Invalid email or password, try again";
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid email or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }
```

User.php

```
public $validate = array(
'email' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'A email is required.'
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => array('email', true),
                'message' => 'Please fill a valid email address.'
            ),
            'isUnique' => array(
                'rule' => array('isUnique'),
                'message' => 'This email id already exist.'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Please enter password.'
        )
);
```

But when i login it shows "This email id already exist." message for right email address but i want to skip this validation if email id is exist in database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `beforeValidate()` ([manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforevalidate)) callback which is triggered each time before validation mixed with some kind of flag which you will be set in login method.

So in your model add flag field:

```
protected $skipEmailUniqueValidation = false;
```

Then add some setter for it:

```
public function setSkipEmailUniqueValidation($value = true) {
    $this->skipEmailUniqueValidation = $value;
}
```

And add `beforeValide()` method:

```
public beforeValidate(array $options = array()) {
    if ($this->skipEmailUniqueValidation) {
        unset($this->validate['email']['isUnique']);
    }
    return parent::beforeValidate($options);
}
```

Last thing to do is setting `skipEmailUniqueValidation` in your action by:

```
public function login() {
    $this->layout = 'login';
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        /** these conditions are used to call validations forcefully **/
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            $this->User->set($this->request->data);
            $this->User->setSkipEmailUniqueValidation(true); // here
            if($this->User->validates()) {
            }
        } else {
            $errors = $this->User->invalidFields();
        }
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            //$errors = "Invalid email or password, try again";
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid email or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}
```